# Unable To update QGIS to newest version on Linux Mint

Tags: qgis, linux

I've read many posts with similar issues, but not exactly the same.
I have QGIS installed on Linux Mint Vanessa and I want to update to the newest version as the repository version is old, so I want to update to QGIS 3.32.

I've followed the instructions,and I've tried many different changes to try to get my system to update. I've downloaded the key using

```
sudo mkdir -m755 -p /etc/apt/keyrings  # not needed since apt version 2.4.0 like Debian 12 and Ubuntu 22 or newer
sudo wget -O /etc/apt/keyrings/qgis-archive-keyring.gpg https://download.qgis.org/downloads/qgis-archive-keyring.gpg
```

My current /etc/apt/qgis.sources.d list is:

```
Types: deb deb-src
URIs: https://qgis.org/debian/
Suites: vanessa
Architectures: amd64
Components: main
Signed-By: /etc/apt/keyrings/qgis-archive-keyring.gpg
```

I've tried changing Debian to Ubuntu, as well as Vanessa to Focal, Jammy, and the other options. When I run `sudo apt install qgis` I get a bunch of dependency issues so that doesn't work.
I've also went into Software Sources and added a deb file, that didn't seem to do anything either. Right now I have deb https://qgis.org/ubuntu vanessa main

What am I missing?

I don't understand the process completely.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have run the following command to install the signing key correctly as per the [download instructions](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html):

```
sudo wget -O /etc/apt/keyrings/qgis-archive-keyring.gpg https://download.qgis.org/downloads/qgis-archive-keyring.gpg
```

Now run:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qgis.sources
```

And make sure it contains the following:

```
Types: deb deb-src
URIs: https://qgis.org/debian
Suites: jammy
Architectures: amd64
Components: main
Signed-By: /etc/apt/keyrings/qgis-archive-keyring.gpg
```

If it doesn't, then either

- delete the contents (`ctrl-k` a few times) or
- exit nano (`ctrl-x`), delete the file (`sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qgis.sources`) and reopen it (`sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qgis.sources`)

And then copy and paste the above in (`ctrl-shift-v` will paste in the terminal). Make sure you copy the above *after* you use `ctrl-k` in nano.

Notes:

- Undo any changes you've made using Software Sources
- Your distribution should be `jammy` not `vanessa` as Linux Mint 21 is based on Ubuntu 22.04. You can check via the terminal command `cat /etc/os-release` and look for `UBUNTU_CODENAME=`
- If you've got a `/etc/apt/qgis.sources.d` file you've done something wrong and should delete it.  The file should be `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/qgis.sources`
- It doesn't matter if you have `URIs: https://qgis.org/debian` or `URIs: https://qgis.org/ubuntu` in `qgis.sources`

Comment: I have done that and little variations several times, and still I am only able to get QGIS 3.22

Comment: I just installed Mint 21 Vanessa (in a VM), followed the instructions and got QGIS 3.32 without any problem. Make sure you have completely undone any changes you made. Particularly through software sources or any PPA/UbuntuGIS repos that you may have tried.